# Script execution using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I want the output of the script that is executed in remote server to be saved in a text document in the remote server. I tried many ways but nothing seems to be work out.

```
---
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: slave
  remote_user: root
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
     - name: Transfer the script
       copy: src=uptime.sh dest=/home/  mode=0777

     - name: Execute the script
       command: sh /home/uptime.sh >> /home/output
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you try the `shell` module instead of `command`? e.g. `shell: sh /home/uptime.sh >> /home/output` or `shell: "sh /home/uptime.sh >> /home/output"`

Comment: Thank you so much :) .... it's working